# PHP bringing back all rows instead of requested

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a query that is bringing back all rows from the table instead of the fields I have specified. Can you see any mistakes in this? I'm using codeigniter.

Thanks in advance!

```
unset($conditions);
    $conditions['conditions'] = array("accountid"=>$this->sessionInfo['database_account_id'],
                "DATE_FORMAT(salestart,'%Y-%m-%d')"=>$today,
                "shop"=>"london"
                );
    $conditions['group_by'] = "item";
    $conditions['fields'] = "accountid, item, count(uniqueid) as totalitems, sum(options) as totaloptions, colour";
    $today_sales = $this->Database_Model->selectData("sales",$conditions);
```

My model is:

```
public function selectData($table,$condition=array()) {
    if(isset($condition['fields'])){
        $fields = $condition['fields'];
    }
    else{
        $fields = "*";
    }
    $this->Database->select('*');
    $this->Database->from($table);
    if(isset($condition['conditions'])){
       $this->Database->where($condition['conditions']);
    }
    if(isset($condition['group_by'])){
        $this->Database->group_by($condition['group_by']);
    }
    if(isset($condition['order_by'])){
        $this->Database->order_by($condition['order_by']);
    }
    if(isset($condition['where_in'])){
        $where_in = $condition['where_in'];


        foreach($where_in as $key =>$value){
            $this->Database->where_in($key,$value);
         }
    }
    if(isset($condition['joins'])){
        $joins = $condition['joins'];
        foreach($joins as $join){
            $this->Database->join($join['table'], $join['joinWith'],$join['type']);
         }
    }
     $query = $this->Database->get();

     return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: not sure what the -1 is for if I'm missing something please let me know, thanks!

Comment: What's `$this` referring to? What is `Database_Model`?

Comment: I have included my Database_Model....

Comment: Use `$this->Database->select($fields, true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
$this->Database->select('*');
```

to this

```
$this->Database->select($fields);
```

Comment: Thanks! Working now.